# Taking limit under a multiple integral

Tags: integration, limits

I would like to study the following limit of an integral:
$$
\lim_{C\to\infty}\int_{E_n} \prod_{j=1}(\boldsymbol u^T \cdot \boldsymbol v)^{m_jC} d\boldsymbol u
$$
where $\boldsymbol u$ and $\boldsymbol v$ are vectors of length $n$, and $m_j$ positive reals for all $j$. Therefore the integrand is a multivariate polynomial in the variables $\boldsymbol u$. The integration region is the unit $n$-simplex $E_n$. Vector $\boldsymbol v$ can be scaled to have whatever norm we like.

How should one proceed in taking this limit?